# sort a multidimensional array in php in a given structure

Tags: php, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have an array like this:

```
$myarray = array (
    array(
        array('Restaurant' =>
            array(
                'name' => 'Rodeo Ranch',
                'distance' => 1.2
            ),
        ),
        array('Menu' =>
            array(
                'title' => 'Steak with fries'
            )
        )
    ),
    array(
        array('Restaurant' =>
            array(
                'name' => 'City Bar',
                'distance' => 0.9
            ),
        ),
        array('Menu' =>
            array(
                'title' => 'Burger with Chicken'
            ),
            array(
                'title' => 'Hot-Dog'
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Now, I want to sort the array, that the nearest Restaurant is on top. I tried this:

```
$myarray = array_msort($myarray['Restaurant'], array('distance'=>SORT_ASC));
```

This does not work. Any help?

Unfortunately, I should not change the array because for further handling it needs to be in this structure.

Thank you for any hints and tips.

Comment: Here: http://www.php.net/manual/pl/array.sorting.php - choose one with callback and plac your logic there

Answer (score 1):

You could use a closure:

```
usort($myarray,function($a,$b) {
   if( $a['Restaraunt']['distance'] < $b['Restaraunt']['distance'] ) return -1;
   if( $a['Restaraunt']['distance'] > $b['Restaraunt']['distance'] ) return 1;
   return 0;
});
```

Comment: `$a['Restaraunt']` is undefined.

Comment: oops, sorry it's:  $a[0]['Restaraunt'], and $b[0]['Restaruant'] respectively.

Answer (score 0):

`usort()` is your friend when trying to sort arrays with a more complicated structure:

```
usort($myarray, function(array $a, array $b) {
    $aDistance = $a[0]['Restaurant']['distance'];
    $bDistance = $b[0]['Restaurant']['distance'];

    if($aDistance == $bDistance) {
        return 0;
    }

    return $aDistance > $bDistance ? 1 : -1;
});
```

Note that `usort()` is not stable: if two restaurants have the same distance, their order in the sorted array is undefined.

Comment: Thank you. I see this will be more complicated than I thought. I have more than two Restaurants in the array. It's everytime another number of restaurants (depending on a query for searching). I think, usort will not work as simple as above right. As I understand, this works only to sort two array in this structure. So I have to think about it again.